# a value of type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "double**"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, malloc

I use C language and I have problem with malloc

```
  double** matrix = malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double*));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double));
  }

  return matrix;
}`
```

Comment: Is that the full message? Are you compiling in C mode?

Comment: I make code where MallocMatrix function: allocates dynamic memory for a matrix. First, it is allocated for an array of pointers to strings, then memory is allocated for one-dimensional arrays, which are strings of a string matrix. And I have error: a value of type “void” cannot be used to initialize an entity of type “double**

Comment: For better or worse, your compiler is probably applying C++ rules to your C code.  It probably says "a value of type `void *` cannot be used" (a pointer rather than plain `void`; there are no values of type `void`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

malloc returns a void-pointer

**void** ***malloc(size_t size);**

so you will have to typecast this to double**

```
double** matrix = (double**)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double*));
```

Comment: Note that a true C compiler does not require the cast, but a C++ compiler does.

Comment: I fix as you said but now I have a problem with matrix[i] = malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double)); It says a value of type “void*” cannot be used to initialize an entity of type “double*

Comment: same thing, you will have to typecast to double*. matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(double));

Comment: It seems like you're compiling this as C++ code based on the errors you're getting. Can you confirm this is C code, a `.c` file, and being compiled *as* C?